# C how do i import/link glfw with gcc on linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker, glfw

this shit doesn't work. ***why?***

```
gcc -c -Wall src/*.c -g -m64 && gcc -Iinclude *.o -o bin/debug/main -Lusr/local/lib -l libglfw && ./bin/debug/main
```

i get this linking error when trying to build the glfw window example

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l libglfw
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How do i import/link glfw and what is going wrong? I tried dynamically linking from `usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglfw.so` but it didn't help. I'm pretty new to gcc and linux so i could just be stupid.

**EDIT:**
the comments pointed out a few mistakes i made so here's the new command, which is wrong too for some reason:

```
gcc -c -Wall src/*.c -g -m64 && gcc -Iinclude *.o -o bin/debug/main -L/usr/local/lib -lglfw && ./bin/debug/main
```

the new error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `main':
/home/basti/dev/OpenGL/src/main.c:26: undefined reference to `glClear'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You probably want `-L/usr/local`..., with a slash after the `L`, unless you actually mean a directory under your current directory.

Comment: ... and `-l libglfw` should probably be `-lglfw` .

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Thanks to comments i managed to fix linking and didn't realize i had to import other opengl stuff.

In case somone is searching for an answer to the same problem here's my debug build command for sublime text 3:
`gcc -c -Wall src/*.c -g -m64 && gcc -Iinclude *.o -o bin/debug/main -lglfw -lGLU -lGL && ./bin/debug/main`